# python datetime strptime does not match format

Tags: python, python-datetime

This is the code i want to run

```
from datetime import datetime

date="08/30/2017 10:02 pm (PDT)"

dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p (%Z)')
```

date is a string with value `08/30/2017 10:02 PM (PDT)`

It looks perfectly fine to me, but python give me this error:

```
time data '08/30/2017 10:02 PM (PDT)' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p (%Z)'
```

The code was ran on a remote machine with python 2.7. However, if I manually type those code into a local python terminal. It works perfectly fine.

Is there any thing that can make the difference? 
(I tried to change date between unicode/str, makes no difference)

Comment: Im guessing local Python is also 2.7?

Comment: @SterlingButters yes

Comment: strptime uses underlying C library (see strftime) -- if you are running on different OS, it can be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of the `TZ` environment variable.  `time.strptime` uses the `TZ` variable to disambiguate time zone abbreviations because they would not be unique otherwise.  I can reproduce the match error with `TZ=Europe/Berlin`, but get a successful parse with `TZ=America/Tijuana`.

Another source for the discrepancy could occur if the other machine has TZ data which uses numeric time zones only, which was a somewhat recent change (in 2017) for certain time zones (which would also mean the machine on which this works would have a woefully outdated time zone database).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works if you replace `PDT` with `UTC` - it seems PDT is not recognized:

```
from datetime import datetime

date="08/30/2017 10:02 pm (UTC)"

dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p (%Z)')

print(dt) # 2017-08-30 22:02:00
```

vs.

```
date="08/30/2017 10:02 pm (PDT)"

dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p (%Z)')

print(dt) #  time data '08/30/2017 10:02 pm (PDT)' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p (%Z)'
```

(https://pyfiddle.io/ in 2.7 mode)